# XML attribute parsing with python and ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

folks!
I'm trying to parse some weird formed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<analytics>
  <standard1>
    ...
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="agentname" value="userx userx" />
      <attribute name="agentpk" value="5" />
      <attribute name="analytics:callid" value="757004000003597" />
      ...
      <attribute name="wrapuptime" value="0" />
    </attributes>
  </standard1>
  <standard2>
    ...
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="agentname" value="userx userx" />
      <attribute name="agentpk" value="5" />
      <attribute name="analytics:callid" value="757004000003597" />
      ...
      <attribute name="wrapuptime" value="0" />
    </attributes>
  </standard2>
  <engines>
  ...
  </engines>
</analytics>
```

Since both *name* and *value* are attributes, I have no idea how to access *value* by *name* without looping through the whole attributes subsection with a foreach cycle.

Any ideas how to get a direct access using ElementTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple *XPath expression* to filter `attribute` element by the value of `name` attribute. Sample working code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<analytics>
  <standard>
      <attributes>
        <attribute name="agentname" value="userx userx" />
        <attribute name="agentpk" value="5" />
        <attribute name="analytics:callid" value="757004000003597" />
        <attribute name="wrapuptime" value="0" />
      </attributes>
  </standard>
</analytics>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
print(root.find(".//attribute[@name='agentname']").attrib["value"])
```

Prints:

```
userx userx
```

Beware that `xml.etree.ElementTree` has a [limited XPath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

Comment: @e-pirate well, I am still not sure what exactly you are up to, but you can adjust the expression(s), e.g. `.//standard2//attributes/attribute[@name='agentname']`..hope that helps.

Comment: @e-pirate Please, see the updated XML. I need to select what attributes subsection of what particular standardX to search through.

Comment: @e-pirate okay, let's approach it differently. Could you post what is your desired output for the presented in the question XML? Thanks.

Comment: The `.//standard2//attributes/attribute[@name='agentname']` is exactly what I asked for.